# SQL Error: ORA-32361

Tags: oracle, real-time, materialized-views

When I create real-Time Materialized Views in Oracle Database 12c Release 2 I get SQL Error: `ORA-32361`. What does it mean?

My view is simple, without any aggregation.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_t_mv
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION
AS
SELECT et.some_value_1, et.some_value_2                         
FROM   example_t et WHERE et.some_value_2 < 10;
```

> SQL Error: ORA-32361: cannot ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION for the
>   materialized view

Comment: Please post entire error message

Comment: Interesting. I got the same error in 12c R2 when I ran some other create mv statement with `ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION` after creating mv logs and there aren't  any lines further after this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Create MVLog and try to create the MV

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON example_t
WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(some_value_1, some_value_2)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```